# How to create a "sub-error handler" in procedure?

Tags: vba, error-handling

I have  a vba procedure including an error handler.
Now I have found that this part of the procedure might cause an error en therefore trigger the error handler:

```
'zoekt de juiste brigade bij de ingevulde luchthaven
For c = 2 To aantalrijen
        Cells(c, 6).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Database").Range("A:D"), WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Range("E" & c).Value, Worksheets("Database").Range("A:A"), False), _
        WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Range("F1").Value, Worksheets("Database").Range("1:1"), False))
Next c
```

I do not want the "general"  error handler to be triggered, I want this part of the procedure to continue with the next c if it causes an error.

How can I make this procedure not to trigger the error handler when this specific part causes an error (cannot find the value in the search matrix), but continues with the next c?

Comment: One idea would be to put this part in a single sub - and do the special error handling there - using `On error resume next` together with a comment, why you use the error-handling.

Comment: I did, it worked fine now (at least the procedure checked all the rows (6344) in the worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

### Match Data Without Raising an Error

[image]

**A Quick Fix**

- Use late binding i.e. use `Application` instead of `WorksheetFunction`.

```vb
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Database")
Dim ws As Worksheet: ' Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
 
Dim r As Long, aantalrijen As Long
 
'aantalrijen = 11
 
For r = 2 To aantalrijen
    With Application
        ws.Cells(r, "F").Value = .Index(sws.Range("A:D"), _
            .Match(ws.Cells(r, "E").Value, sws.Range("A:A"), 0), _
            .Match(ws.Range("F1").Value, sws.Range("1:1"), 0))
    End With
Next r
```

**EDIT**

- The following should be by far more efficient. Your feedback is expected.

```vb
Const DST_FIRST_ROW As Long = 2

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Database")
Dim ws As Worksheet: ' Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
 
Dim aantalrijen As Long: ' aantalrijen = 11
 
Dim rCount As Long: rCount = aantalrijen - DST_FIRST_ROW + 1
 
With Application
    ws.Range("F2").Resize(rCount).Value = .Index(sws.Range("A:D"), _
        .Match(ws.Range("E2").Resize(rCount), sws.Range("A:A"), 0), _
        .Match(ws.Range("F1").Value, sws.Range("1:1"), 0))
End With
```

Comment: I tried you suggestion but it caused my excel to freeze.

Comment: That's probably got nothing to do with my code. I have tested it before posting. Are these sheets in the same workbook, the one containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`)? Also, have you checked the value of `aantalrijen`? If it's a huge number, it will take forever ('freeze').

Comment: No I know, but that was just what I encountered. I added a timer to compare both solutions. Yours took 06:38 (mm:ss) and Ike's took 06:33 (mm:ss). But both work fine.

Comment: it would be best to ask another question to make the code more efficient i.e. a proper code should run in under a second for 6k rows. But you need to share more information i.e. the complete code, some screenshots, where exactly the data is located i.e. you can't expect the code to run efficiently when you're looping through so many cells and using entire columns and rows. In a nutshell, it's an XY problem: you have decided that this is the correct way but it isn't.

Comment: No, I never had the idea that I might have the most efficient code. I would have to make up data because I work with confidential data so I cannot simply make screenshots and upload them here. Besides that, I used code that I used years ago and did not create myself but an Excel expert we hired. That just ran the code for the range of cells that was counted (so not entire columns and rows)

I will ask a different question to see how the complete code can be made more efficient.

Comment: I have added a more efficient solution.

Comment: I hope to try your added suggestion tomorrow when I'm back at work again.